# Парсинг данных php

Tags: php, ссылки

С помощью чего лучше реализовать данную схему:

1. На моем сайте есть сформированная ссылка, которую скрипт должен открыть
2. Перейдя по ссылке формируется ответ в адресной строке браузера
3. Необходимо скопировать ответ и вернуть его на мой сайт
4. Вывести ответ пользователю на экран

При этом пользователь не должен наблюдать самих переходов и тд, т.е. нужно сразу вывести ответ.

---

Подскажите куда лучше копать?

Comment: Что-то такое наверное: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php. Возвращает весь путь и данные GET массива которые должны быть в адресной строке. Но я бы подождал более опытных человечков которые подойдут сюда с минуты на минуту =)

Comment: вы опишите лучше что поисходит при обычном нажатии на ссылку, куда перенаправляется браузер, и еще что. какие данные вам надо получить. и какие из этих процессов вам нужно скрыть.  Пока что у меня впечатление, что у вас есть ссылка, вы туда жмете, и браузер переходит туда, а потом редиректится еще куда то, и вот это конечное куда-то вам надо изначально получить и показать его URL. В общем, пока что вопрос не шибко ясен. Что за ответ в адресной строке? там url  с каким-то хэшем который нужно получить?

Comment: а так в целом вам нужен аякс запрос, к своем пхп скприту. Передаете ему ссылку, Открываете ее средствами пхп и следуете всем редиректам. Получаете последний URL, на который был редирект, и возвращаете его пользователю как аякс-ответ.

Comment: это получение токена VK api, проблема в том, что права на wall.post дают только если в качестве ред redirect_uri указываешь https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html. Но в этом случае пользователь остается на странице ВК, ему надо скопировать адресную строку, потом передать мне... Я бы хотел автоматизировать этот процесс. Вот думал может быть curl подойдет...

Comment: Пользователь должен тебе передать свой токен ... попахивает грязными делишками. На этот случай так и задумано, чтоб не было подобных xss

Comment: Если тебе нужно побороздить чью то стену - тебе не обязательно иметь токен пользователя, чью стену ты решил обкатать. Достаточно иметь токен от свей учётки

Comment: dev_nul, вместо того, чтобы высказывать свои бредовые предположения и писать не по теме, лучше по существу! Первично пользователю открывается диалоговое окно ВК, где есть весь перечень доступов с которыми он соглашается, нажимая кнопку ОК

Comment: Туда он попадает со своими **КУКАМИ**, иначе - авторизация. Чтоб это провернуть - тебе как минимум куки у него нужно угнать. А вот это уже грязно